# Is this use of 'que' unusual?

Tags: que

This is a sentence from Philippe Soller's 1958 story *Le Défi*:

> Claire aurait pu moins bien parler que je ne l'eusse pas senti.

I find the 'que' confusing and am not sure how to understand it. How can this sentence be translated into English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means basically "Même si Claire avait moins bien parlé je ne l'aurait pas senti.".

In English you can do away with a translation of that "que", the proper use of modals and syntax will supply the needed meaning.

- Had  Claire  spoken less well, I wouldn't have felt it.

This use of the conjunction "que" is meant to assert a negative or positive outcome of a supposed situation. It can also be omitted in French.

- Il aurait eu un bon repas, il ne l'aurait (même) pas remarqué, alors autant lui servir de la tambouille.
- Il aurait eu un bon repas **qu**'il ne l'aurait (même) pas remarqué, alors autant lui servir de la tambouille.
- Vous l'auriez traité honnêtement qu'il aurait quand même essayé de vous rouler.

In the sentence under inquiry the past conditional 2nd form ("eusse senti") is a literary variant of the 1rst form. ([ref.](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/discussion/3044/le-conditionnel-passe-2e-forme))

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is literary, just like the *conditionnel passé deuxième forme* in *j'eusse senti*.

What it means in everyday's French:

> *Même si Claire s'était moins bien exprimée, je ne m'en serais pas rendu compte.*

A still literary but more current way to say it:

> *Quand bien même Claire aurait moins bien parlé [que] je ne l'aurais pas senti.* (Either a comma or *que* is required)

The person speaking is very likely infatuated with Claire.

Comment: That's *subjonctif* not *conditionnel*, right?

Comment: @costrom The *conditionnel passé deuxième forme* and the *plus que parfait du subjonctif* are two sides of the same coin. As the consequence of the condition didn't occur, I prefer to state it is a *conditionnel*. See https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4141

Comment: Very interesting, I haven't seen this 'feature' before! It is very similar to the Spanish use of *subjunctivo*, however.